# Declaring variables in python

Tags: python

I wanted parse a file to search one word and print next line i have written python script as follows

```
infile = open("s.sdf","r")
output = open("sample.txt","w")
d = None
HD = None
HA = None
M = None

for line in infile:
      if line.startswith(">  <PUBCHEM_COMPOUND_CID>"):
         d = infile.next().strip()
         print d      
      elif line.startswith(">  <PUBCHEM_CACTVS_HBOND_DONOR>"):
         HD = infile.next().strip()
         print HD
      elif line.startswith(">  <PUBCHEM_CACTVS_HBOND_ACCEPTOR>"):
         HA = infile.next().strip()
         print HA
      elif line.startswith(">  <PUBCHEM_MOLECULAR_WEIGHT>"):
         M = infile.next().strip()
         print M

      print "%s \t  %s  \t  %s  \t  %s" %(d,HD,HA,M)
      output.write("%s  \t  %s  \%s \t  %s" %(d,HD,HA,M))
```

But unfortunately i getting an error as follows

```
None None None None

None None None None

None None None None

None None None None
.......
```

Can anybody tell me how to solve this..

Thanks in Advance

N

Comment: Please use the `{}` button in the SO editor to format your code (or indent everything 4 spaces).  I fixed it for you.

Comment: Well, that probably means that none of your `startswith` conditions are matching. Post some of your data. Also, add some `print` statements under the conditions so you can see when they are getting triggered (if they are) -- debugging 101.

Comment: Looks like XML, use a python XML processor instead. There are thousands of questions and answers on this topic on SO.

Comment: There is no such think like declaration in Python. New variable is simply new value in your namespace local dictionary.

Comment: Furthermore you need to clear your variable each time in your loop. Strip method always return string so no line match the `startswith` and all variable stay as `None`.

Comment: @MattH, it's not XML. OP's code references an `.sdf` extension, which turns out to be a chemical data file. It uses angle brackets, but only to identify header lines. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_format#SDF

Answer (score 1):

To skip lines that do not match those strings add a check:

```
if any(bool(x) for x in d, HD, HA, M):
    print ...
    output.write
```

Try running the script in a debugger:

```
$ python -m pdb your_script.py
```

and see what variables are there and what's wrong. Since PDB is not convenient, you might want to install [`ipdb`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) or [`pudb`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb).